# pipe-lining using wget or curl on linux

Tags: hard-drive, dd, io, file-download, aria2

I would like to know how can I download a file from the internet using wget and/or curl by separating the file into even segments and downloading the file using 8 or 16 direct links, substantially increasing download performance.

PS: what about aria2c? can it use concurrent download links?

Answer (score 1):

by installing aria2c with `apt install aria2c` command and using these arguments I can download my files at full bandwidth using multiple links to the same file:

`aria2c -c -V -j 1 -k 5M -s 16 "link"`

```
-c, --continue[=true|false]  Continue downloading a partially downloaded
                              file. Use this option to resume a download
                              started by a web browser or another program
                              which downloads files sequentially from the
                              beginning. Currently this option is only
                              applicable to http(s)/ftp downloads.

                              Possible Values: true, false
                              Default: false
                              Tags: #basic, #http, #ftp
```

```
-V, --check-integrity[=true|false] Check file integrity by validating piece
                              hashes or a hash of entire file. This option has
                              effect only in BitTorrent, Metalink downloads
                              with checksums or HTTP(S)/FTP downloads with
                              --checksum option. If piece hashes are provided,
                              this option can detect damaged portions of a file
                              and re-download them. If a hash of entire file is
                              provided, hash check is only done when file has
                              been already download. This is determined by file
                              length. If hash check fails, file is
                              re-downloaded from scratch. If both piece hashes
                              and a hash of entire file are provided, only
                              piece hashes are used.

                              Possible Values: true, false
                              Default: false
                              Tags: #basic, #metalink, #bittorrent, #file, #checksum
```

```
 -j, --max-concurrent-downloads=N Set maximum number of parallel downloads for
                              every static (HTTP/FTP) URL, torrent and metalink.
                              See also --split and --optimize-concurrent-downloads options.

                              Possible Values: 1-*
                              Default: 5
                              Tags: #basic
```

```
 -k, --min-split-size=SIZE    aria2 does not split less than 2*SIZE byte range.
                              For example, let's consider downloading 20MiB
                              file. If SIZE is 10M, aria2 can split file into 2
                              range [0-10MiB) and [10MiB-20MiB) and download it
                              using 2 sources(if --split >= 2, of course).
                              If SIZE is 15M, since 2*15M > 20MiB, aria2 does
                              not split file and download it using 1 source.
                              You can append K or M(1K = 1024, 1M = 1024K).

                              Possible Values: 1048576-1073741824
                              Default: 20M
                              Tags: #basic, #http, #ftp
```

```
-s, --split=N                Download a file using N connections. If more
                              than N URIs are given, first N URIs are used and
                              remaining URLs are used for backup. If less than
                              N URIs are given, those URLs are used more than
                              once so that N connections total are made
                              simultaneously. The number of connections to the
                              same host is restricted by the 
                              --max-connection-per-server option. See also the
                              --min-split-size option.

                              Possible Values: 1-*
                              Default: 5
                              Tags: #basic, #http, #ftp
```

Comment: Yes, `aria2c` supports downloading files from different links as well as splitting the file into several chunks and downloading. You should've accepted your answer. (`wget` doesn't have such an option.)